# Not all watched tags show the "Eye" icon on the All Questions page

Tags: bug, tag-watching

Noticed that not all tags in my watched list show with the new "Eye" icon in the tag, is this a bug?

I read [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375509#comment1251286_375509) on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375509/202529) in [this question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/202529):

> This was a race condition bug. We have "fixed" this by partially reverting the label approach back to using a colored background. We lose info that way, but it gives us an opportunity to revisit how the watched styles are being added to the page. –
> Ben Kelly
> Staff
> Mod
> Jan 25 at 19:37

In the below image every tag is in my watch list but only the first two are rendered, so it appears this is still an issue? The actual render seems hit and miss as sometimes they show with the "Eye" icon and on some questions they don't.

[image: Example of missing watch icon]

Same question but looking at a specific tag question list

[image: Example from tag question view]

Comment: If you’re explicitly searching for `[vbscript]`, then this tag is not taken into account for the watch highlighting or the icon. This has always been the case.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I didn't know that, just seemed a weird inconsistency but that explanation makes perfect sense.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @zcoop98 probably. However, if you ask whether it's documented *somewhere useful*, then probably not.

Comment: Well, we created the documentation just now with this question :)